# Is there a way to edit a the layout of a Google Doc published as a webpage?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to edit the layout of my Google Doc when it's published as a webpage so it’s not all sitting on the left side of the screen. My aim is to get it to look similar to the way I had it looking as a Doc.

Original Document[image]

Document as Webpage[image]

Is there a way to edit the HTML/CSS of the webpage to correct its layout?

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: You can  edit the html, but it'll only reflect in your browser. If this bothers you, provide feedback to Google in the app. Alternatively, if you have time, create your own web app  using [tag:google-apps-script-web-application], where you can control the html flow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!